# How to reuse a button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The case is that I made my first app in Android Studio,
the app consist in adding a text(By a `EditText`) and being translated to `TextView` by pressing a button, and the problem is:
I want the user to be able to edit the text and a new translation will come up by pressing the button again, which is not possible in my code, I don't know how to make the button clickable more than once.

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
            EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.escribiraqui);
            TextView T=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.traduccion);
            Button TRAD=(Button) findViewById(R.id.traducir);
              //
              //HERE IS THE REST OF THE CODE THAT TRANSLATES THE TEXT
              //TO MORSE CODE
              //
            TRAD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

            }
        });
    }
```

I don't know what to add for the code to allow the bottom to be clicked more than once(That is the issue).

Comment: just change the text in the edit text field and press you TRAD button again

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe ?

```
        EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.escribiraqui);
        TextView T=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.traduccion);
        Button TRAD=(Button) findViewById(R.id.traducir);




        TRAD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
          String textToBeConverted = e.getText().toString();
          //
          //HERE IS THE REST OF THE CODE THAT TRANSLATES THE textToBeConverted
          //TO MORSE CODE
          //

        }
    });
```